# How to check many variables in Python if not null?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a python scraper code for OpenData and I have one question about : how to check if all values aren't filled in site and if it is null change value to null.

My scraper is [here](https://github.com/Pytlicek/SK_Prison_and_Court_Guard/blob/0cf1a13a45b06acefe28cef63c85cb2ab9bdc8fa/scraper.py).

Currently I'm working on it to optimalize.

My variables now look like:

```
    evcisloval = soup.find_all('td')[3].text.strip()
    prinalezival = soup.find_all('td')[5].text.strip()
    popisfaplnenia = soup.find_all('td')[7].text.replace('\"', '')
    hodnotafaplnenia = soup.find_all('td')[9].text[:-1].replace(",", ".").replace(" ", "")
    datumdfa = soup.find_all('td')[11].text
    datumzfa = soup.find_all('td')[13].text
    formazaplatenia = soup.find_all('td')[15].text
    obchmenonazov = soup.find_all('td')[17].text
    sidlofirmy = soup.find_all('td')[19].text
    pravnaforma = soup.find_all('td')[21].text
    sudregistracie = soup.find_all('td')[23].text
    ico = soup.find_all('td')[25].text
    dic = soup.find_all('td')[27].text
    cislouctu = soup.find_all('td')[29].text
```

And Output :

```
scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys=["invoice_id"],
                                    data={  "invoice_id":number,
                                            "invoice_price":hodnotafaplnenia,
                                            "evidence_no":evcisloval,
                                            "paired_with":prinalezival,
                                            "invoice_desc":popisfaplnenia,
                                            "date_received":datumdfa,
                                            "date_payment":datumzfa,
                                            "pay_form":formazaplatenia,
                                            "trade_name":obchmenonazov,
                                            "trade_form":pravnaforma,
                                            "company_location":sidlofirmy,
                                            "court":sudregistracie,
                                            "ico":ico,
                                            "dic":dic,
                                            "accout_no":cislouctu,
                                            "invoice_attachment":urlfa,
                                            "invoice_url":url})
```

I googled it but without success.

Comment: _if it is null change value to null_: If it is `null`, then it is already `null`, you do nothing. Do you mean `"null"` as a string?

Comment: if the values are not filled in what will they be?

Comment: If you run bulk upload you need to have something as a value. Real date or null. Scraped site has 2 date values one for invoice accepted and one when is invoice paid. If you're in elastic ten you're able to select from this dates. But another use case is select from elastic fields with null values and then inform System administrator of this site that he has not good data and that it is in conflict with law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read your attached link, and it seems what you want is

```
evcisloval = soup.find_all('td')[3].text.strip() or "NULL"
```

But be careful. You should only do this with strings. If the part before `or` is either empty or `False` or `None`, or `0`, they will all be replaced with `"NULL"`

Comment: This is my python scraper. Maybe it helps to someone :
http://pastebin.com/j911H5qZ

Comment: A git diff is probably more useful https://github.com/Pytlicek/SK_Prison_and_Court_Guard/commit/9c528b59406a940e1bcf305ebd69a912b19bc997

Answer (score 2):

First, write a configuration dict of your variables in the form:

```
conf = {'evidence_no': (3, str.strip),
        'trade_form': (21, None),
         ...}
```

i.e. key is the output key, value is a tuple of id from `soup.find_all('td')` and of an optional function that has to be applied to the result, `None` otherwise. You don't need those Slavic variable names that may confuse other SO members.

Then iterate over `conf` and fill the `data` dict.

Also, run `soup.find_all('td')` before the loop.

```
tds = soup.find_all('td')

data = {}
for name, (num, func) in conf.iteritems():
    text = tds[num].text

    # replace text with None or "NULL" or whatever if needed
    ...

    if func is None:
        data[name] = text
    else:
        data[name] = func(text)
```

This will remove a lot of duplicated code. Easier to maintain.

Also, I am not sure the strings `"NULL"` are the best way to write missing data. Doesn't sqlite support Python's real `None` objects?

Comment: Defintely more elaborate than my suggestion. Might be overkill if the function is the same for every variable though.

Comment: Many thanks , I'm going to rewrite code without Slovak in variable. I need null because I plan to export as json and import data into Elastic, and if you need to make operations with date field it must be set or null.

Comment: Yes, use `None`, not `Null`. SQLite and Postgres both support `None`.

Comment: Yes, but I'm planning to import data to Elastic and then you need correct date value or null. This is easiest way like change strings when it finish.